# mongoose query find with period operator

Tags: mongodb

I have one mongo query like this

```
Employee.find({'services.hr.contacts' : {$eq : user._id }}, {_id : 0})
```

i want this `'hr'` should change dynamically with variable like

```
let varr ='hr';
Employee.find({'services.${varr}.contacts' : {$eq : user._id }}, {_id : 0})
```

i have tried with this

```
Employee.find({`services.${varr}.contacts` : {$eq : user._id }}, {_id : 0})
```

but it's not working. How can i achieve this??

Comment: Just enclose it within `[]`. **[`services.${varr}.contacts`]**. Here is the example https://jsfiddle.net/jf54sbzL/

Answer (score 0):

You can do a simple string concatenation to form your query.

Try this:

```
let varr ='hr';
Employee.find({'services.'+varr+'.contacts' : {$eq : user._id }}, {_id : 0})
```

You can also write the second line as below

```
Employee.find({'services.'+varr+'.contacts' : user._id }, {_id : 0})
```